# why my contact form displaying differently in firefox?

Tags: html, css

I have created a form it's fine look in chrome

But i check to firefox than now show properly i m trying many times but not find out solution

any one correction my form

Chrome result [image]

and firefox result show is

[image]

***[Demo link is](http://tinkerbin.com/52Mco43C)***

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS or link to webpage for people to evaluate the problem.

Comment: Welcome to cross browser web development. And also how am I supposed to guess when you show no code

Comment: Code is available under the demo link ...

Comment: Firefox seems to not respect the `bottom: 0;` value where Chrome uses the label as the container to define the size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**input** is the [Replacing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements) element then you have to define **height** & **width** to it for the cross browser capability.

Check this http://tinkerbin.com/hwxXoCkj

Answer (score 1):

You havent fixed width/height for input. Check the updated [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxvdh/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/Sxvdh/1/

Comment: nice answer @Sowmya plus one for your answer.......... but sandeep's is also gud because he has deeply explained about the bug why it was happening

Answer (score 0):

I personally would have styled the form more like this (not saying you should, just offering an alternative).

http://jsfiddle.net/qZfdp/2/

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field text">
        <label>Name *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="field textarea">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    margin: 25px;
    width: 592px;
    border: solid 3px #c7d9e0;
    padding: 60px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius:5px;
}

label {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

input,
textarea {
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 335px;
}

.field {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75) inset;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border:solid 1px #d8d5d5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,245,245,1) 28%, rgba(216,213,213,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,245,245,1) 28%,rgba(216,213,213,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,245,245,1) 28%,rgba(216,213,213,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,245,245,1) 28%,rgba(216,213,213,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(247,245,245,1) 28%,rgba(216,213,213,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}
​
​
```